# How do I validate mm:ss format using javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, testcomplete

I am automating a scenario in testcomplete tool using Javascript
So I have to verify a time format in mm:ss format) Eg:- (20:55)
But at one condition, the time will be displayed in 'mmm:ss' format.In a scenario time 120 minute is displayed as 120:00 format. That also I have validate. So in short I have to validate both format
mm:ss & mmm:ss .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to validate it.

```
var time = '120:50';
if (time.match(/\d+:[0-5]\d/)) {
    // time is valid
}
```

This will match any number of minutes, but will only match a valid number of seconds.

Comment: I found the specified 'mmm:ss' or 'mm:ss' formats a little vague, what are actual valid minute values? 00-999? If you knew this you could make the first `\d+` part of the regular expression more specific, eg. `\d{2,3}` if any two or three digit number is valid.

Comment: @Wayne can I use this for both format - mm:ss and mmm:ss ?

Comment: That's true.  My regular expression allows for any number of minutes - for example, 89721:54 would be valid.  The regular expression could be refined if there is a maximum number of allowable minutes.

Comment: It will find both of those valid.  However, it will also find mmmmm:ss valid.  If you want it to only match mmm:ss and mm:ss, change it to /^\d{2,3}:[0-5]\d$/.

Comment: @WayneAllen Thanks a lot wayne.It works perfectly. Text I retrieve for time is getting as 120 : 50 (space in before and after column) . So what modification I should do for this  /^\d{2,3}:[0-5]\d$/ regular expression ?

Comment: If it is always a single space, you can use /^\d{2,3}\s:\s[0-5]\d$/